# subsetting on two conditions in loop

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data.frame in R which I want to subset depending on two conditions: Firstly the rows shouldn't be duplicates and secondly if they are duplicates, only the row with b==1 should be returned. Instead of the expected five rows, I get all seven rows of this sample df returned. What is the cause?

**EDIT: Sry, the loop actually works. I just forgot an `[i]` at `df$b`.. Still the second part of the question, how this can be optimized is to be answered ;)**

```
a <- c(rep("A", 2), "B", rep("C",2), "D", "E")
b <- c("ws_12","dr_12","ws_12","ws_12","dr_12","ws_12","dr_12")
df <- data.frame(a,b)

result <- data.frame()
for (i in seq_along(df$a)) {
  if (duplicated2(df$a)[i] == FALSE) {
    result <- rbind(result, df[i,])
  } else if (duplicated2(df$a)[i] == TRUE && substring(df$b,1,2)[i] == "ws") {
    result <- rbind(result, df[i,])
  }
}
```

I'm new to programming and R and maybe there's some basic thing I get wrong. Can this also be done in an easier way?

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df$a),]`

Comment: @Sotos we might need to order on `b` before running your code, in case `b` is not ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, negated `duplicated` selects the first seen row. Thus, to achieve your result, we can just `order` on `b` and remove duplicates,

```
df <- df[order(factor(df$b, levels ='ws_12')),]
df[!duplicated(df$a),]
#  a     b
#1 A ws_12
#3 B ws_12
#4 C ws_12
#6 D ws_12
#7 E dr_12
```

Comment: This is valid for my sample data here, but not for my actual data, since the b-values are not 1,2 but character-values. Thus, I want to have it solved in a condition.

Comment: What do you want to keep? `dr_12` or `ws_12`?

Comment: those who start with "ws". I also changed my code. It's indicated there